# Insert into oracle database, but there are three columns to which I dont' want duplicates of

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have this code/query that runs successfully (from java, to insert data into an oracle table)

```
String sqlInsert = "insert into TableName (CWT_ID,EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,TRAVEL_DATE,TRAVEL_FROM,EXPENSE_AMT,EXPENSE_CUR,ZIP_FILENAME,INVOICE_ID,INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER) " + "VALUES (sequenceName.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

(I use PreparedStatement later on to assign values to the "?,?,?,?..." but that's irrelevant to my question

However, I am trying to figure out how to avoid inserting a row, if that row contains the same ZIP_FILENAME,INVOICE_ID AND INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER as another row already/previously added.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `dual` with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery. Do note: this requires three more parameters to be added to prepared statement for `ZIP_FILENAME, INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER` values:

```
String sqlInsert = "insert into TableName (CWT_ID, EMPLOYEE_EMAIL, TRAVEL_DATE, "
                 + "                       TRAVEL_FROM, EXPENSE_AMT, EXPENSE_CUR, "
                 + "                       ZIP_FILENAME, INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER) "
                 + " select sequenceName.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? "
                 + " from dual "
                 + " where not exists(select 1 from TableName "
                 + "                  where (ZIP_FILENAME = ? "
                 + "                    and  INVOICE_ID = ? "
                 + "                    and  INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER = ?));"
```

Comment: so the three extra parameters in the prepared statement would have the same values as the ones I previously assigned to ZIP_FILENAME, INVOICE_ID and INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER right? Also do you know if this is any better or worse than the other answer?(creating unique index)

Comment: Correct. Not sure about unique index as it may raise an error in application layer if you attempt to insert index violation (i.e., duplicate data). This query can be used with any set of values.

Comment: @mchl45 . . . Such a query might introduce race conditions if two concurrent queries attempt to insert the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_tablename_3 on tablename(ZIP_FILENAME, INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I would just have to run that code ONCE and for all? Also, after that "unique index or constraint" is added, what exactly will happen once I'm about to add a row that has the same of those 3 values as another row already existing in the table? Will the program crash, or the row will just be ignored(not added)?

Comment: @mchl45 . . . You run the code once and the database will ensure that the table has no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE into TableName dest
USING (select sequenceName.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? from dual) src
ON (dest.ZIP_FILENAME=src.ZIP_FILENAME and dest.INVOICE_ID=src.INVOICE_ID 
       and dest.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER=src.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER)
when matched then update
set dest.CWT_ID=src.CWT_ID, dest.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL=src.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,dest.TRAVEL_DATE=src.TRAVEL_DATE, 
    dest.TRAVEL_FROM=,dest.EXPENSE_AMT=,dest.EXPENSE_CUR=src.EXPENSE_CUR
when not matched then
insert VALUES (src.CWT_ID,src.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,src.TRAVEL_DATE,src.TRAVEL_FROM,src.EXPENSE_AMT
              ,src.EXPENSE_CUR,src.ZIP_FILENAME,src.INVOICE_ID,src.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER)
```

Comment: I just saw this answer. Do you know if it's any better than the response that uses DUAL with NOT EXISTS?